# Android Studio - not detecting device

Tags: android-studio, usb, tablet, detection

I have got a problem. Today I bought tablet CAVION BASE 7 QUAD and now I want to deploy app on it but Android Studio doesnt detect it.

I have Debugging option ON.
Have you got any tips on how to make it work?

Comment: I once had a similar problem with a Huawei phone; I had to download its usb driver, which came with the phone suite. Maye you need to find its driver too.

Comment: Thank You. I will try, but It may be hard becouse this brand is not that well known :|